# How do I use data from a Model in multiple ViewModels, using MVVM and Caliburn Micro

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I really need your help in clarifying something for me; I am unable to find answers on the internet and even though my question is quite often asked; it's never shown what people mean with the accepted answers.

My issue is this:

I have a ShellViewModel; on this ShellViewModel I want to show a PageTitle. However; I **also** want this PageTitle to be displayed in **another** ViewModel; that is being displayed **inside** of ShellViewModel.

in VB.Net I would just create a public string PageTitle and reference that from the other form (e.g. textbox.text = MainForm.PageTitle) ; but this doesnt seem to work in C#/WPF/MVVM..

*how* do I create a "global variable" that can be set and retrieved from multiple places; while all having the same info?

I tried a few things; this works, but only on ShellViewModel (inaccessible for other ViewModels)

This part only works once; but I still have the issue that I create a New instance on this ViewModel; so any other ViewModel would still get another data..

I am really, really confused in how to do such a menial task ... who is willing to help a lost soul?

===============================[edit]======================================
okay.. so I have something that works;
Could someone please verify if this is the correct way to do it?

```
namespace ServiceTools.UserInterface.Models
{
    public class PageTitleModel

    {
        public static string Title { get; set; }
        public PageTitleModel()
        {
            Title = "Something something, You dont see me actually.. right?!";
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<object> {
    
    //Property for the Page title
    public string PageTitle
    {
        get { return PageTitleModel.Title; }
        set
        {
            PageTitleModel.Title = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => PageTitle);
        }
    }

    public ShellViewModel()
    {
        PageTitleModel.Title = "Hello World";
        // Set the Application Titlebar and DisplayName
        SetTitles(PageTitleModel.Title);
    }
    
    public void SetTitles (string Title)
    {
        //Title of the window
        this.DisplayName = Title;
        PageTitle = Title;
    }
}
```

```
namespace ServiceTools.UserInterface.ViewModels
{
    public class OrderRegistrationViewModel : Screen
    {

        //private string PageTitle = PageTitleModel.Title;
        //Property for the Page title
        public string PageTitle
        {
            get { return PageTitleModel.Title; }
            set
            {
                PageTitleModel.Title = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => PageTitle);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This seems to sync the Title between the two views...
Could someone please verify if this is the way to go?

Comment: A Model is *any* class you want to call that way. You can have a Customer class, perhaps loaded from a database, and display it on any screen or ViewModel that accepts a Customer

Comment: `PageTitle` is a property, not an object anyway. What you did in VB was hard-code access from one form to the other, a very bad practice. There's no difference between VB and C# in this anyway. In both languages, different forms and different elements could bind to the same object property, or resource

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know it's bad practice; that's why I am trying to "convert" myself away from it; but I am unable to figure out how..

Comment: In both cases, just pass the same objects to all forms. Or use a `Customer` property and set it before showing the property.

Comment: hmhm.. that sounds simple; but I am unable to convert that sentence into working code.. hence Why I asked the question in the first place :) (Sorry, I am really unable to do this seemingly simple thing and it freaks me out)

Comment: Views display stuff like titles. Why can't you just use a relativesource binding in the child view to the datacontext.titleproperty of the parent?

Comment: I don't know... why can't I? .. at this moment I am trying to get it to work while asking the internet for best ways to do it. the codesample i've put up in my question is how I am currently trying to solve it.. I do not know much of the bindings yet - let alone relative bindings :)

Answer (score 0):

Every Screen (ViewModel) already has this when they are using Screen as their inherited type.  They have a built-in property called `DisplayName` of course you could create a `BaseViewModel` of type screen and recreate the wheel if you choose.  This is a result of the `IScreen` (which has `IHaveDisplayName`) interface which is being implemented in `Screen`.

```
//C#//
public class BaseViewModel : Screen {

  private string _screenTitle; 
  public string ScreenTitle {
        get => _screenTitle;
        set {
             _screenTitle = value;
             NotifyOfPropertyChange();
        }
 }
   
}


//C#//
public class OrderRegistrationViewModel : BaseViewModel {
   public OrderRegistrationViewModel(){
       DisplayName = "Order Registration";
       ScreenTitle = "BumbleBee Tuna";
   }

   
}

<!--XAML -->
<UserControl>
    <!-- Bound by convention via DataContext automagically by CM in the underlying framework -->
   <TextBlock x:Name="DisplayName" />  
   <TextBlock x:Name="ScreenTitle" />
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Hi mvermef; thanks for your answer.. The question was meant to be about generic variables; I choose pagetitle as my test-property, but this could be some other properties as well. I believe your answer does not longer fit the question then?